# Does Adobe recommend we use Flex or HTML5 for our enterprise application development?

Tags: apache-flex

**Does Adobe recommend we use Flex or HTML5 for our enterprise application development?**

*In the long-term, we believe HTML5 will be the best technology for enterprise application development. We also know that, currently, Flex has clear benefits for large-scale client projects typically associated with desktop application profiles.
Given our experiences innovating on Flex, we are extremely well positioned to positively contribute to the advancement of HTML5 development, starting with mobile applications. In fact, many of the engineers and product managers who worked on Flex SDK will be moving to work on our HTML efforts. We will continue making significant contributions to open web technologies like WebKit & jQuery, advance the development of PhoneGap and create new tools that solve the challenges developers face when building applications with HTML5.*

---

is it a positive or negitive for the flex i am a flex developer and i just want to know that weather i have future in flex please geeks answer to my question.....
thank you

Comment: I voted to close, as this is not a programming question. This sort of thing has been re-hashed many times over the past 7 months or so. Check out some Blog Posts I wrote on the topic:  http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2011/11/21/In-Defense-of-Flash and http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2012/5/8/Is-Flex-Dead . Whether you personally have a future developing Flex Applications depends on many things, such as your location / expertise / client base / Employer Interests / etc...

Comment: of course lot of things were posted with thousands lines of analyses and finally saying that we have to wait.........to know the result. My question mainly focused on career not on lot of analysis, Weather flex still will give good career or not just i want that answer itself not lots of analysis so that's the reason why i posed the question thank you for your comments.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex is now becoming part of apache http://incubator.apache.org/projects/flex.html and no one can really tell where the party is going at. But there is a huge interest as far as i can tell in not only keeping Flex alive, but also making it more mature.

Comment: One thing I noticed in the mailing list is that they're saying they're the _most active Apache mailing list_ - that's a pretty good sign. A lot of work going on with the HTML5 compiler too. Imagine if Flex could target Flash, HTML5 and AIR. *Three platforms*, that's a MAJOR advantage for an SDK to have!

Answer (score 2):

From the blog post by Adobe http://blogs.adobe.com/flex/2011/11/your-questions-about-flex.html

***Note the second part of the answer.***

> **> Does Adobe recommend we use Flex or HTML5 for our enterprise application development?**
>
> In the long-term, we believe HTML5 will be the best technology for
>   enterprise application development. We also know that, currently, Flex
>   has clear benefits for large-scale client projects typically
>   associated with desktop application profiles.
>
> Given our experiences innovating on Flex, we are extremely well
>   positioned to positively contribute to the advancement of HTML5
>   development, starting with mobile applications. In fact, many of the
>   engineers and product managers who worked on Flex SDK will be moving
>   to work on our HTML efforts. We will continue making significant
>   contributions to open web technologies like WebKit & jQuery, advance
>   the development of PhoneGap and create new tools that solve the
>   challenges developers face when building applications with HTML5.
>
> **> You said that you believe HTML is the “long-term solution for
>   enterprise applications” – can you clarify this statement?**
>
> HTML5 related technologies (comprising HTML, JavaScript and CSS) are
>   becoming increasingly capable, such that we have every reason to
>   believe that advances in expressiveness (e.g. Canvas), performance
>   (e.g. VM and GPU acceleration in many browsers) and
>   application-related capabilities (e.g. offline storage, web workers)
>   will continue at a rapid pace. In time (and depending upon your
>   application, it could be 3-5 years from now), we believe HTML5 could
>   support the majority of use cases where Flex is used today.
>
> However, Flex has now, and for many years will continue to have,
>   advantages over HTML5 for enterprise application development – in
>   particular:
>
> Flex offers complete feature-level consistency across multiple
>   platforms The Flex component set and programming model makes it
>   extremely productive when building complex application user interfaces
>   ActionScript is a mature language, suitable for large application
>   development Supporting tools (both Adobe’s and third-party) offer a
>   productive environment with respect to code editing, debugging and
>   profiling Our announcements relating to changes in the way Flex SDK is
>   developed do not change the fundamental value-add of Flex or make
>   HTML5 suddenly more capable than it was last week.
>
> We intend to make investments in HTML-related technologies, so that we
>   can help advance HTML5 to make it suitable for enterprise
>   applications.

Comment: "However, Flex has now, and for many years will continue to have, advantages over HTML5 for enterprise application development – in particular:"

Still waiting for this to change in the enterprise development space. The 500lb gorilla in the room that HTML5 advocates ignore is that browser updates and new browsers are *still* regularly breaking complex enterprise applications. Visiting many popular HTML/JS based SDK showcases now, often their examples are simple websites (frequently broken!) or mobile apps which have very little in common with real life data driven web-deployed *applications*.